# Connection to shared network server sometimes stuck connecting, needs restart to fix

Tags: macos, network, finder, sharing

Sometimes on `OS X Yosemite` my connection to a shared network server is stick connecting, while the server is available. `OS X` simply won't connect to it using `Finder` and the `Connect As...` button doesn't respond. It won't eject either. Only a restart fixes everything again, a relaunch of `Finder` doesn't help. I am wondering if there's a fix or easier workaround for this.

[image: Visual example]

**Edit:** I'm not even sure it can connect to any shared computer at all when this happens and it seems `Finder`access is fully broken.

**Update:** I'm going to try a few other methods to connect to the server found on http://www.macworld.com/article/2012153/eight-ways-to-connect-to-a-server.html whenever the issue reoccurs.

**Update:** I found that the process that (I guess) arranges the connection from `OS X` to the server using `SMB` hogs up a lot of memory. The command of the process is `/usr/local/sbin/smbd -D -s /usr/local/etc/smb.conf`. Killing it on the server remounts the drive on `OS X` and makes the slowness disappear. On another note: `OS X` also often mounts multiple instances of the server, appended with -1, -2 etc. I'm still not sure what causes the issue, but at least I have a quicker fix than a reboot.

Comment: What OS on the remote machines? What protocol? AFP, SMB…?

Comment: FreeBSD / SMB. Your comment already helped me a bit while searching for answers to your questions, as I could try to connect using `CMD + K` when the issue occurs again

Comment: Not sure on BSD, but I know that with Windows over SMB, often a Mac can force a master browser election & win it, even when it shouldn't, which messes up sharing until the correct machine can get back master browser status. I force one [Windows] machine in my network to always win the election; fixed a lot of similar 'weirdness'

Comment: Does that mess up other computer's connection with the server as well, or do those issues only apply to the Mac causing the issue? As others (both Macs and PC's) can connect to the server just fine while the problem occurs.

Comment: I used to find it rather randomly affected things, sometimes just one machine, sometimes a few. Since I fixed it to one always-on server, all my woes have vanished. I did have one residual issue for a while, which I fixed with this - http://superuser.com/a/894691/347380 but I don't think that's actually relevant to your situation.

Comment: Seems very helpful, will try those settings as well. I'll update whenever I'm able to try to apply these methods.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact same issue. In my case, both my mac and my nas were configured for jumbo frames. My new switch, however, even thought it supports jumbo frames, did not have jumbo frame support turned on. Knocking the MTU on the mac back down to the standard 1500 MTU (under advanced settings, and the advanced tab in network system preferences) got everything working again.

Comment: Swapped old Netgear router for new one. NAS appeared in finder sidebar; shares showed up, but trying to open one gave the spinning wheel and no contents ever appeared. Couldn't then disconnect; shutdowns required force-quitting Finder. Changed MTU back to 1500 from 9000, and everything worked! (Old router was WNDR3700, new is R6700. Apparently old one handled jumbo frames better!)